# Unable to update google maps location using firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update location form firebase database to google maps in my android application. I have used the onDataChange method from firebase to do so. My issue is that I am still not able to update the location on google maps even if the location for altitude and longitude is changed in the firebase database. Below is my code for the MapsActivity.java class.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    String value;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Location");

      //  myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String [] separated = value.split(",");
                String latiPos= separated[0].trim();
                String longiPos =separated[1].trim();
                String TAG ="VAL";
                double dLat = Double.parseDouble(latiPos);
                double dLong = Double.parseDouble(longiPos);
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(dLat, dLong);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(latiPos+" "+longiPos));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
     //   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
      //  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(value));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `onDataChange` is being invoked and that it's correctly parsing the lat/long values?  Possibly not related to your issue but would recommend you use call `dataSnapshot.getValue()` with java class containing lat/long values...which will use `gson` to deserialize from json string you get back  (though not sure from your description how data is structured in db).

Comment: Yes, I did confirm the values by printing them out in the log.

Comment: One other possible issue might be around timing of  `mMap` being available (i.e. `onMapReady` happening after `onDataChange` callback)...though you should get NPE if that happened...in any case you should probably wait to do your firebase query until `mMap` has been set.

Comment: I thought exactly the same, but when I update latitude and longitude values in firebase the change in values should execute the onDataChange method which eventually should change the marker position to new lat, long values but its not happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I'd suggest to address your issue:

1. Wrap your data stored in `FirebaseDatabase` in a Java object to easily store and retrieve data. Right now 
   you are doing a lot of work to process the data you are storing in your database. So, 
   define a class which represents the data you are storing as a Java object. Then your reads/writes
   to the database will be much easier. Here's an example of a class you can use to represent a map marker
   based on what I've seen in your code above. You can customize it to fit your needs:

   ```
   public class LocationMarker {

       double latitude;
       double longitude;


       /**
        * Required Empty Constructor used by Firebase
        */
       public LocationMarker() {
       }

       public LocationMarker(double latitude, double longitude) {
           this.latitude = latitude;
           this.longitude = longitude;

       }

       public double getLatitude() {
           return latitude;
       }

       public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
           this.latitude = latitude;
       }

       public double getLongitude() {
           return longitude;
       }

       public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
           this.longitude = longitude;
       }


       /**
        * These getters will be ignored when the object is serialized into a JSON object.
        * Since they will be ignored this means that they don't need a corresponding property (field)
        * in the Database. This is how we can return a value without having them declared as an instance variable.
        */

       @Exclude
       public LatLng getPosition(){
           return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
       }

       @Exclude
       public String getTitle(){
           return Double.toString(latitude) + " " + Double.toString(longitude);
       }
   }
   ```

   Now you can much easier write a location to your database.

   ```
   DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
   double latitude = -34;
   double longitude = 151;
   LocationMarker locationMarker = new LocationMarker(latitude,longitude);
   myRef.child("Location").setValue(locationMarker);
   ```

   And Read:

   ```
   myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            LocationMarker locationMarker = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationMarker.class);

            if(locationMarker != null){
                LatLng sydney = locationMarker.getPosition();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                       .position(sydney)
                                       .title(locationMarker.getTitle));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
   });
   ```
2. The calls to `onMapReady()` and `onDataChange()` happen asynchronously.
   That means your challenge is that you have no control over when onMapReady() is called.
   You also don't you have control over when `onDataChange()` is called by your `ValueEventListener`. 
   As written now, the call to your FirebaseDatabase may return before you have a valid `GoogleMap` object. So add your `ValueEventListener` in the call to `onMapReady()`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        addValueEventListener();
   }

   //....

   private void addValueEventListener(){

       if(mMap == null) return;

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  LocationMarker locationMarker = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationMarker.class);

                  if(locationMarker != null){
                  LatLng sydney = locationMarker.getPosition();
                  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                       .position(sydney)
                                       .title(locationMarker.getTitle));
                  }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
        });
   }
   ```

Hope this helps with showing storing and retrieving a map marker to your database. This should store a single marker under "Location". You'll have to make adjustments to your database structure for multiple markers. Also, be sure to remove any added listeners :)